# Combine two large data table

Tags: mysql

We have two tables and I would like to get the result table (as follow). We try this SQL...

```
select table2.CUI_1, table1.STR, table2.CUI_1, table.STR from table1 , table2 
where table2.CUI1 in (select table.cui from table2)
and table2.CUI2 in (select table1.cui from table1)
```

but it is too inefficient(the table1 and table 2 contain million records), and it may not respond correctly. What the SQL is right for this request?
Many thanks

```
table1:  
|CUI|STR|  
|1  | Hi|  
|2  | Ho|  

table2:  
|CUI_1|CUI_2|  
|100  |    1|  
|102  |    2|  
|1    |    2|  

result_table  
|CUI_1|STR|CUI_2|STR|  
|1    | Hi|    2| Ho|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JOIN` its much more efficient then using 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT
    t2.CUI_1,
    t11.STR,
    t2.CUI_2,
    t12.STR
FROM 
    table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t11
    ON t11.CUI = t2.CUI_1
INNER JOIN table1 t12
    ON t12.CUI = t2.CUI_2
```